# What's the benefits of generic MOCK_METHOD over MOCK_METHODn in gMock

Tags: c++, googlemock

In google mock cook_book, it is recommended to migrate to the new MOCK_METHOD.  Besides the new way of writing, is there any performance or compilation time benefits?

Comment: `MOCK_METHODn` is the old way, with limited hard-coded limit.  `MOCK_METHOD` is the modern way.

Comment: For performance, as usual, benchmark. I would say same runtime performance, and possibly faster compilation.

Comment: Benefits? One of them is deprecated (or discouraged), the other is not. One may be removed in future, for the other there are no plans to do that. One offers very limited capabilities, the other allows you to mock a function with any signature.

Comment: By benefits, I mean what's the adding value for new MOCK_METHOD

Comment: There is no other benefit than "it's finally not limited". You can now mock `noexcept` and `const noexcept` functions, you can mock functions with more than 10 arguments, you can use `override` specifier when writing mocks to let compiler check typos for you. You can stay with old `MOCK_METHODX`, it still works like it used to, but modern way is simply more flexible and capable of mocking any method you might have written (even if the language evolves and e.g. new specifier is added to `const` and `volatile`)

Answer (score 1):

Yksisarvien collected several aspects that may be a beneficial.

- `noexcept` and `const` methods can be mocked
- Since `override` explicitly added, using with `const` doesn't cause warning on MSVC 120
- Not limited to 10 parameters, as there is no MOCK_METHOD11 or above.

Also, the `MOCK_METODn` probably won't get any performance boost in the future, like c++20, or other optimization.